# how to create a dictionary whose keys are (i,j) integer pairs with i < j

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, nested-loops

I intend to create thousands of integer pairs, number them and store them in a dictionary. Given a number `n`, my goal is to generate every `(i,j)` pair such that `i<j`.

For instance, if `n=4`, the pairs will be then the dictionary will look like `{(0, 1): 0, (0, 2): 1, (0, 3): 2, (1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 4, (2, 3): 5}`.

I can generate this dictionary by using nested for loops, but it is not efficient when `n` is large. Could someone help me to perform this operation quicker than I currently do?

```
d={}
n=4
temp =0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i <j:
            d.update({(i,j): temp})
            temp+= 1
```

Comment: If this exact example is your actual use case, I would recommend just deriving a formula for the number based on `(i, j)` to save you time and space.

Comment: @Kraigolas Wouldn't that be equivalent to a hashcode? That is the reason I decided to use dict.

Comment: If you use a dictionary, and it has say 10_000_000 elements, you have to compute the result for all of those elements ahead of time, and you need to store the tuples and the results for all of them. If you derive a formula, you do not need to store anything, and you only compute the results you need.

Comment: What do you want this for? Why not a list of lists?

Comment: @KellyBundy Suppose there is an algorithm that returns (12,35). I need to get the corresponding number using this pair as a key. Obviously, I'll have hundreds of such keys

Comment: So you really only use this for such lookups of those original values, you're not modifying the dict after initializing it this way?

Comment: @KellyBundy That is right! That's why what Kraigloas suggested does make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect job for [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) as it will only produce the required combinations:

```py
from itertools import combinations

n = 4
out = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(combinations(range(n), 2))}
```

output: `{(0, 1): 0, (0, 2): 1, (0, 3): 2, (1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 4, (2, 3): 5}`

###### Using your code

*Note that you could rework your code to only produce the required combinations:*

```py
d={}
n=4
temp = 0

for j in range(n):
    for i in range(j):
        d[(i,j)] = temp
        temp += 1

# {(0, 1): 0, (0, 2): 1, (1, 2): 2, (0, 3): 3, (1, 3): 4, (2, 3): 5}
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking it a step further:

```
from itertools import combinations, count

n = 4
out = dict(zip(combinations(range(n), 2), count()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxDoNADAR7v8KlLVElKWh4DBAgljjbMqYIn79cQZFqdqQd/@bH9Nl71LqGFZRcIs32A6W4ReJsZRIdU0yPrtmpCaA44AvszMa3zEmXOP0/KUbdFlLu8MF3RswMHtJWKxmg1h8)

Seems to be slightly faster. Test with n = 1000:

```
191.0 ms  mozway
176.2 ms  kelly
186.8 ms  mozway
177.8 ms  kelly
185.2 ms  mozway
178.6 ms  kelly
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/RasMwDEXf/RV6KbVHKMnCYBT6JWMEN1U2kVg2itLSln175iwbjMH8ZnR17lG66nvk@jnJPHcSAygFJAUKKYqCYEKv5mtCiqIxDuPPsI3hSOyVIo9F/k2sxpywgxBvF3@1bm8gP0GdhOHe78/QRYFz0QMxIE8BxSva3xwrnt/Qsivg0bmPldfjMPzFnahVe6P0//a3knXOGcNwgKosS7MYdBO3i8LLKlqsBa/wAPXaoTkdiO16vl3yBWTfI8qhyrglk4QyfLt52lX54hG2sAGrmVFhnbuXnV3TsA/YNG6ePwE)):

```
from timeit import repeat
from itertools import combinations, count

def mozway():
    return {k:v for v,k in enumerate(combinations(range(n), 2))}

def kelly():
    return dict(zip(combinations(range(n), 2), count()))

n = 1000
for func in [mozway, kelly] * 3:
    t = min(repeat(func, number=1))
    print('%5.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
```

Comment: :D I thought about it for a moment but sticked to the classical `enumerate`, ❤️ itertools ;)

Comment: @mozway If I'm not mistaken, both `enumerate` and `itertools.count` were introduced in Python 2.3, so neither appears to be more classical than the other :-)

Comment: I rather meant in the sense `builtin` vs `import`, not the best choice of word ;)